# MySQL - Check if 2 start and end parameter is not between start and end in database record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this db design:

```
Tasks table
- id
- start (datetime)
- end (datetime)
```

In my application, I passed 2 start and end date parameters so that it will check if these parameters are not between those start and end in my db record.

Example, in my DB record I have the following data:

```
id  |       start         |        end
001 | 2022-01-19 07:00:00 | 2022-01-19 09:00:00
```

Then the parameter that I passed into my application are:

```
start = 2022-01-19 09:00:00 
end = 2022-01-19 10:00:00
```

I want to check if these start and end time parameters are between those records in my DB. Ideally, this should return `0 rows` because the start time can be equal to the end time in the record in the DB.

Another scenario is that when I passed these parameters to my application:

```
start = 2022-01-19 06:00:00
end = 2022-01-19 07:00:00
```

It should also return `0 rows` because the end time can be equal to the start time in the record in the DB.

This is mySQL query, but this is wrong because it returns a result:

```
select * from tasks WHERE (start >= '2022-01-19 09:00:00' AND start <= '2022-01-19 10:00:00') OR (end >= '2022-01-19 09:00:00' AND end <= '2022-01-19 10:00:00')
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need in "not between"? `start = 2022-01-19 06:00:00; end = 2022-01-19 10:00:00` (includes) and `start = 2022-01-19 07:10:00; end = 2022-01-19 08:50:00` (is included) - does some of them matches and must be returned? *This is mySQL query, but this is wrong because it returns a result* You do not need in adjacent intervals, hence use strong, not weak, compare operators.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8c20d2a7f6ef7934657eb6ec090c2c0 - for each separate row in `ranges` tell does the output must be 0 or 1 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you wish to detect collisions between intervals and return a final count if any with the passed parameters.

So, we would be checking if any event occurs after the passed in params' event has ended or if any event only occurs and ends before the passed in params' event starts. This ensures no collision. We will negate(`!`) the result to say there is a collision(if any).

You can follow the below format:

```
select * 
from tasks 
WHERE !(start >= {end_parameter_time} OR end <= {start_parameter_time})
```

More precisely for your case/example, it would be:

```
select * 
from tasks 
WHERE !(start >= '2022-01-19 07:00:00' OR end <= '2022-01-19 06:00:00')
```

[**Online Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rRmD4acc7Yw6vVemLXcgcN/0)

Answer (score 1):

The query to test if date range `[@d1, @d2)` overlaps date range `[start, end)` is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
WHERE @d2 > start
AND   @d1 < end
```